# Watson Conversationでの改行について

Tags: json

Watson Conversationで、Watsonからの回答メッセージを改行入りで表示させたいのですが、
下記のような方法を試しても改行されずに表示されてしまいます。

＜例：下記のように表示させたい場合＞
　あいうえお
　かきくけこ

Dialogの「Then respond with:」に下記のように入力

> あいうえお\nかきくけこ
>   あいうえお\r\nかきくけこ

Try it outで動作確認すると・・・

> あいうえお\nかきくけこ
>   あいうえお\r\nかきくけこ

とそのまま表示されてしまいます。

Json Editorで下記の方法も試しましたが、同じ結果でした。

> あいうえお\\nかきくけこ
>   あいうえお\\r\\nかきくけこ

Conversationで回答を改行させるには、どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

すみません、自己解決しました。

①Dialogの「Then respond with:」に下記のように入力

> `あいうえお\nかきくけこ`

②Json Editorで開き、バックスラッシュを１個削除

> `あいうえお\\nかきくけこ`　⇒ `あいうえお\nかきくけこ`

③Try it outでは改行無しで表示されますが、Slack上では改行されて表示されました。